# Datepicker is required in php form with hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm creating a php form to post data. One of the elements is a Datepicker JS element. I pass the input from the datepicker to a hidden input field. Now I want this datepicker to be required. If I make the input field required it doesn't seems to work because it's hidden, and it must stay hidden. Anyone know the best way to do this?

The code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 ">
    <div id="date"></div>
    <label>Datum geselecteerd: </label>
    <input type="hidden" id="datefield" name="date" required/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var selected;
        $('#date').datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date){
            return [date.getDay() != 1 & date.getDay() != 2 & date.getDay() != 3 & date.getDay() != 5 & date.getDay() != 0, ''];
        }});
        $(function() {
            $('#date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
            $('#date').on("change",function(){
                selected = $(this).val();
                document.getElementById('datefield').value = selected;
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You can check if `date` is set on form `.submit(callback)` for example

Comment: @Sojtin can you tell me a bit more please?

Comment: If the datepicker is chosen, make it visible to the user. If not, simply store the date the form is filled without relying on datepicker js.

Comment: why don't you use the datepicker on an input-text-field and hide that instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can use .submit() in jquery which is called when form is submitted and you can check if date field is filled.
For more info here: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Also you should check it with php where you process the data the form sent you and if it is not filled you should send user back to fill the form again with a warning that he didnt fill a field

example:

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="get">
<input type="hidden" id="datefield" name="date" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
   if(  $("#datefield").val().length === 0 ) {
    alert('not filled');
    }
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: $('#bestelformklant').submit(function(ev) {
   if(document.getElementById('datefield').value == ""){
    ev.preventDefault();
   }
  }

Comment: looks like he's not going into the code. Maybe due to the fact I'm using a button as submit?

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit">VERSTUUR BESTELLING</button>
     </form>

Comment: when i run this fiddle it gives an alert. But when I run it on my server (www.melkerhei.be/php/testcheck.php) it does not give an alert or error..

https://jsfiddle.net/en9cj6ge/

Comment: i tried your checkout.php and found that the field is now read only and visible :) so it works as you intended? btw...i dont know what hosting you are using but you should disable directory listing